# What does this i386 os code mean? The code is for resetting the system

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, intel

```cpp
/* jump to reset vector. esp := 0 */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    PRINT("reset\n");
    _eflags = 0; // interrupt disabled
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("\
        mov $0x0, %%esp;\
        jmp *%0"
        :: "r"(_vector[0]));
    /* never return here */
    return 0;
}
```

This is i386 os code, and I have difficulty understanding it. What does the code below mean? Especially I want to know what is "r"(_vector[0]).

```cpp
__asm__ __volatile__ ("\
        mov $0x0, %%esp;\
        jmp *%0"
        :: "r"(_vector[0]));
```

Comment: It sets the ESP register to zero and then jumps to the address given in `_vector[0]`. Presumably [the reset vector, i.e. the code where bootup normally starts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reset_vector), as the comment already says. - I can't say more without knowing what environment / system this is supposed to run on (looks to me like an embedded system).

Comment: @CherryDT Thankyou for the advice. It was my first time posting so I didn't know how to post a code. I just edited it.

Comment: About your last edit: You can read [in this GCC inline assembly tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15971/Using-Inline-Assembly-in-C-C) what the `"r"` means. In short, it means that the argument `_vector[0]` is passed into the assembly block in a `r`egister of the compiler's choice which you can access as `%0`.

Comment: You can look at how the compiler filled in the asm template string by looking at the compiler's asm output.  https://godbolt.org/  Obviously you need a definition of `_vector`, which this snippet is missing.  Also obviously, a user-space program can't reset the machine, unless your OS is very weird and runs user-space with privilege level 0 (aka ring 0 = kernel mode), so it doesn't make sense to put this code inside a normal `main()` .